# calculus gets challenged

Tags: calculus

A maths problem: Calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a function. The limit of the function at $x=a$ exists iff both right hand and the left hand limits exist. For those to exist, the difference between the limiting values and $f(x)$ should be less than $\epsilon$, however small it be whenever the difference between them and $x$ is less than $\delta$, however small it be.

BUT, the difference between $L_-$ and $L_+$ (the limiting values of left and right hand limit respectively) is $2 \cdot \epsilon$. But $2 \epsilon$ is greater than $\epsilon$, which doesn.t satisfy the condition for the limiting values to be equal.

Here is one example that makes it clear:

$\lim_{ x \to a} f(x)$. Here the difference between limiting value and functional value is so small that we can consider them to be the same. But the difference between the left hand limiting value and the right hand limiting value is twice the difference between one of them and $f(x)$ which is not so small to be considered to be zero.

Comment: Uh.... What?...

Comment: So, twice something small is something big?

Comment: Couldn't you use different epsilons for the left and right hand limits so that the overall difference is less than epsilon?  That would be my suggestion if I'm guessing your issue correctly.

Comment: Space,space,space...between lines, too!

Comment: And your first claim is false: the limit of a function at $\,a\,$ exists iff both left hand and right hand limits exists **and they're equal** .

Comment: There is no question, though I have this feeling the OP is trying to ask why sometimes we get somewhere somehow $\,2\epsilon\,$ instead of $\,\epsilon\,$ . Of course, if $\,\epsilon\,$ is arbitrary so is $\,2\epsilon, 5\epsilon\;\;or\,\,10^{10^{10}}\epsilon\,$ , and there's no real difference between them in this respect.

Comment: It might help a little to "rewrite" the definition of limits. On could write for every $\epsilon>0$ their is a $\delta_{\epsilon}>0$ such that $x-a<\delta_{\epsilon}\implies |f(x)-L_+|<\epsilon$ for the right hand limit (limits and left hand limits also have similar modifications). Note that all we did was to rename $\delta$ to $\delta_{\epsilon}$ to emphasize the relation. We can then pick any epsilon, and plug $\epsilon/2$ into the statement and get out a $\delta_{\epsilon/2}$.

Comment: @BabyDragon, that's actually how we learned analysis in our freshman year :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the left and right limits of a function exist and agree; equivalently, for any sequence $x_n$ with $\lim x_n = x$ we have $\lim f(x_n) = y$ for some real number $y$, provided that $x_n \leq x$ for all $n$, or $x_n \geq x$ for all $n$.

Consider an arbitrary sequence $x_n$ which has the limit $\lim x_n = x$. If all but finite number of $x_n$ lie on the one side of $x$, we immediately have $\lim f(x_n) = y$. Otherwise, split the sequence into two subsequences, one with all $x_{n_k} \leq x$ and one with $x_{m_k} > x$. $\lim f(x_{n_k}) = \lim f(x_{m_k}) = y$, in other words, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ all $f(x_{n_k})$ and all $f(x_{m_k})$ are in $(y - \varepsilon, y + \varepsilon)$, except for a finite number of exceptions. Since the union of finite sets is again a finite set, all $f(x_n) \in (y - \varepsilon, y + \varepsilon)$, except for a finite number of exceptions, Q.E.D.

Comment: ok.. satisfied..

Answer (score 1):

There's no relationship necessary between the value of $f(a)$ and the limiting values. If you removed an arbitrary point from the line $f(x)=x$, $f(x)$ would still have a limit at that point. Also there's no one difference between any single value and $f(x$) unless $f(x)$ is constant. Differences of values are values, differences of functions are functions.

Also, why do you claim $L_--L_+=2\epsilon$?

Comment: for the LHL = RHL, their difference should be less than any pre assigned no. but, we already have a no. epsilon, which is smaller than the difference between the two numbers. so LHL not = RHL

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are saying. By "limiting values" do you mean $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}f(x)$? By "the line $f(x)=x$" do you mean the line $y=x$? Using $g(x)$ or any other symbol that hasn't already been used would be less confusing. For each $x$, $f(x)-f(a)$ is a value; this seems contextual.

Comment: @kiranadhikari, The difference in the VALUES on the left and on the right gets arbitrarily close to 0, not the difference in the limits. The limit is the value the function's getting arbitrarily close to.

Comment: @robjohn I'm sorry. Yes. Yes. Okay. Exactly the OP's problem.